# Why does it take such a long time for the initial deployment?

Tags: android

I'm wondering why it takes such a long time for the android or web app to be compiled and loaded the first time. Subsequently, changing the code and redeploying the app takes a much shorter time. Can anyone give me a technical reason why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, every time you compile a program, only the .cpp files (source code files) that were changed are compiled. After compilation, .obj (compiled code) files are stored in a temporary directory. If a file was  not updated, the compiler will just use the old .obj files in the temp directory. After this, the new and old .obj files are all linked together into an executable.

This is similar for all compilers - as long as you don't change the code in a file, then it won't have to be recompiled the next time. This usually makes compiling and deploying your project faster the second time around.

Comment: so im guessing that if you make numerous changes, then the deployment time will increase correspondingly..

Comment: yeah, the more files you change the more files the compiler has to compile.